# R data processing involving strsplit

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
> df
                   V1         V2    V3 V4       V5                 V6 V7
1  chr1:859582-899582    AHR.pfm 33440  - 9.188581          gcacgcaac NA
2  chr2:859582-899582   AIRE.pfm  7387  + 7.982141 TCTGGTTCAGTTGGATGC NA
3  chr1:859582-899582 AIRE.3.pfm 30639  - 8.127811 aaaaccaaacaaacaaaa NA
4 chr13:859582-899582   ALX1.pfm 11835  + 7.485710       GTAATTGTGTTA NA
5 chr21:859582-899582 ALX1.1.pfm 16260  + 9.529333       GTAATTAATTTA NA
6  chrX:859582-899582 ALX1.2.pfm 20686  + 9.241755       CTAATTAATTTA NA
```

I want to append multiple new columns to this dataframe and all of these columns will have information from within this data frame. Details are below:

1. append column **chr** having values strsplit(df$V1,":")[[1]] (split
   first column values on : and assign the first index to this new
   column)
2. append column **start** having values strsplit(df$V1,":")[[2]] =>
   strsplit(df$V1,"-")[[1]] (split first column value firstly on : take
   2nd index and then split it on - and assign first index to this new
   column)
3. append column **end** having values df$start + length(df$V6) (add in
   the value of start, the length of characters in V6 column)
4. append column **TF** having values strsplit(df$V2,".")[[1]] (split
       second column values on . and assign the first index to this new
       column

So that appended new column looks like:

```
chr1 859582 859591  AHR
chr2 859582 859600  AIRE
chr1 859582 859600  AIRE
chr13 859582 859594 ALX1
chr21 859582 859594 ALX1
chrX 859582 859594  ALX1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) tidyr/dplyr** This separates column `V1` into `chr`, `start` and `end` columns and then appends a `TF` column with everything before the first dot in `V2`.   An alternative to the `mutate` might be `separate(V2, "TF", extra = "drop")` which would drop `V2` and put `TF` in its place.  Add the `separate` argument `remove=FALSE` if you want to keep the original columns as well.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate(V1, c("chr", "start", "end"), convert = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(TF = sub("[.].*", "", V2), end = end + nchar(V6))
```

giving:

```
    chr  start    end         V2    V3 V4       V5                 V6 V7   TF
1  chr1 859582 899591    AHR.pfm 33440  - 9.188581          gcacgcaac NA  AHR
2  chr2 859582 899600   AIRE.pfm  7387  + 7.982141 TCTGGTTCAGTTGGATGC NA AIRE
3  chr1 859582 899600 AIRE.3.pfm 30639  - 8.127811 aaaaccaaacaaacaaaa NA AIRE
4 chr13 859582 899594   ALX1.pfm 11835  + 7.485710       GTAATTGTGTTA NA ALX1
5 chr21 859582 899594 ALX1.1.pfm 16260  + 9.529333       GTAATTAATTTA NA ALX1
6  chrX 859582 899594 ALX1.2.pfm 20686  + 9.241755       CTAATTAATTTA NA ALX1
```

**2) no packages**  A way to do it with only base R is:

```
nms <- c("chr", "start", "end")
df2 <- cbind(df[-1], 
 read.table(text = sub("-", ":", df$V1), sep = ":", as.is = TRUE, col.names = nms), 
 TF = sub("[.].*", "", df$V2), 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 df2 <- transform(df2, end = end + nchar(V6))
```

giving:

```
> df2
          V2    V3 V4       V5                 V6 V7   chr  start    end   TF
1    AHR.pfm 33440  - 9.188581          gcacgcaac NA  chr1 859582 899591  AHR
2   AIRE.pfm  7387  + 7.982141 TCTGGTTCAGTTGGATGC NA  chr2 859582 899600 AIRE
3 AIRE.3.pfm 30639  - 8.127811 aaaaccaaacaaacaaaa NA  chr1 859582 899600 AIRE
4   ALX1.pfm 11835  + 7.485710       GTAATTGTGTTA NA chr13 859582 899594 ALX1
5 ALX1.1.pfm 16260  + 9.529333       GTAATTAATTTA NA chr21 859582 899594 ALX1
6 ALX1.2.pfm 20686  + 9.241755       CTAATTAATTTA NA  chrX 859582 899594 ALX1
```

**Note:**  `df` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
                   V1         V2    V3 V4       V5                 V6 V7
1  chr1:859582-899582    AHR.pfm 33440  - 9.188581          gcacgcaac NA
2  chr2:859582-899582   AIRE.pfm  7387  + 7.982141 TCTGGTTCAGTTGGATGC NA
3  chr1:859582-899582 AIRE.3.pfm 30639  - 8.127811 aaaaccaaacaaacaaaa NA
4 chr13:859582-899582   ALX1.pfm 11835  + 7.485710       GTAATTGTGTTA NA
5 chr21:859582-899582 ALX1.1.pfm 16260  + 9.529333       GTAATTAATTTA NA
6  chrX:859582-899582 ALX1.2.pfm 20686  + 9.241755       CTAATTAATTTA NA"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: @g-grothendieck Thank you very much for the multiple solutions. There is just one problem with this solution and that is `end` column. `end` column should contain value which is `start + length of characters in df$V6`. For example for first row it will be  `859582 + 9 = 859591` instead of `899582? which is what I am getting now. Can you please guide me how can I do that? Thanks again

Comment: OK. Have added that.

Comment: @g-grothedieck Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236519/replacing-for-loop-with-foreach-loop/49237000?noredirect=1#comment85479099_49237000) of replacing for loops with foreach loop or parSapply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function `fun` to do this, with reapeted calls to `sapply/strsplit`.

```
fun <- function(DF){
    chr <- sapply(strsplit(DF[[1]], ":"), `[`, 1)
    start <- sapply(strsplit(DF[[1]], ":"), `[`, 2)
    end <- as.integer(sapply(strsplit(start, "-"), `[`, 1)) + nchar(DF[[6]])
    start <- sapply(strsplit(start, "-"), `[`, 1)
    TF <- sapply(strsplit(DF[[2]], "\\."), `[`, 1)
    cbind(DF, data.frame(chr, start, end, TF))
}

fun(df)
```

Note that the data must be read in with both columns `V1` and `V2` of class `character`, not `factor`. If they are of class `factor` coerce them to `character` first or, if applicable, set argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

**DATA.**

```
df <-
structure(list(V1 = c("chr1:859582-899582", "chr2:859582-899582", 
"chr1:859582-899582", "chr13:859582-899582", "chr21:859582-899582", 
"chrX:859582-899582"), V2 = c("AHR.pfm", "AIRE.pfm", "AIRE.3.pfm", 
"ALX1.pfm", "ALX1.1.pfm", "ALX1.2.pfm"), V3 = c(33440L, 7387L, 
30639L, 11835L, 16260L, 20686L), V4 = c("-", "+", "-", "+", "+", 
"+"), V5 = c(9.188581, 7.982141, 8.127811, 7.48571, 9.529333, 
9.241755), V6 = c("gcacgcaac", "TCTGGTTCAGTTGGATGC", "aaaaccaaacaaacaaaa", 
"GTAATTGTGTTA", "GTAATTAATTTA", "CTAATTAATTTA"), V7 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", 
"V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```

Comment: @rui-barradad Thank you very much for the solution. There is just one problem with this solution and that is `end` column. `end` column should contain value which is `start + length of characters in df$V6`. For example for first row it will be  `859582 + 9 = 859591` instead of `899582? which is what I am getting now. Can you please guide me how can I do that? Thanks again.

Comment: `end <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(start, "-"), `[`, 1)) + nchar(df$V6)` This is what I was looking for the `end` column.

Comment: @Newbie Just edited with that modification. See if this is it.

Comment: For the end column you have to select first index (which is start column) and then add nchar in that. It will be: `end <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(start, "-"), [, 1)) + nchar(DF[[6]])` Notice that I am selecting first index.